# Mysql query that can search with a criteria of total summation of an object

Tags: mysql, sql

hello please help me with this mysql query,

i want to select the rows that have a summation of 17 or less when the quantity columns is added together and the searched item is Pen in an ascending order based on id.

My table structure is like this:

```
ID quantity item 
------------------
1         5 Pen
2         3 Pen
3        10 Books
4         7 Pen
5         4 Pen
6         8 Pen
7         1 Rubber
```

so i want my output to be like this, because when the quantity is added together for the pen that can be equal to 17, it will have the below rows

```
ID quantity item 
------------------
 1        5 Pen 
 2        3 Pen
 4        7 Pen
 5        4 Pen
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `quantity` column of your expected output does not add to 17, in any order.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I have included it because the total of 17 pens falls under the column with ID 5 so I cant remove it since the query should be in ascending order without skipping a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one idea... slower than Gordon's but (for the time being at least), more accurate...

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
           FROM my_table a
           JOIN
              ( SELECT x.*
                     , SUM(y.quantity) total
                  FROM my_table x
                  JOIN my_table y
                    ON y.item = x.item AND y.id <= x.id
                 WHERE x.item = 'pen'
                 GROUP
                    BY x.id
                HAVING 17 > SUM(y.quantity)-x.quantity  
                   AND 17 <= SUM(y.quantity)
              ) b
             ON b.item = a.item
            AND b.id >= a.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but when i need like 5 items, i get the all rows with 5 items instead of just one.

Comment: Is there a tweak to it?

Comment: @Rhynix Tweaked (I think)

Comment: Ok, I was hoping for the other way round, so if I get 3 pens, the result will be row one, if I get 8, the result will be row 1 and 2, if I get 10 pens, the result will be row 1,2 and 4. I hope u get it now. I want to get the rows that contain the sum of my search. Am sorry for the first miss understanding, I hope it's clear now. Can you help please.

Comment: That's not what this does??

Comment: I have seen the changes you have made. Works like a charm !!! Thanks alot mate. 

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you have a threshold of 17 and want the maximum number of rows that do not exceed the threshold.  If so, then a cumulative sum is the right approach, and variables are the most efficient method in MySQL:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@sum := @sum + quantity) as sumq
      from t cross join
           (select @sum := 0) params
      where item = 'Pen'
      order by id
     ) t
where sumq <= 17;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon Linoff, its working but when i put a quantity like 3 Pen, its not displaying yest i should be getting the first row since i has more than 3 and its the first one.

Comment: is there something i should add or remove?

Comment: @Rhynix . . . I don't understand the issue with 3 Pen.  The first row has "5" and that exceeds the threshold.  Hence, no rows are selected for that threshold.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping for the other way round, so if I get 3 pens, the result will be row one, if I get 8, the result will be row 1 and 2, if I get 10 pens, the result will be row 1,2 and 4. I hope u get it now. I want to get the rows that contain the sum of my search. Am sorry for the first miss understanding, I hope it's clear now. Can you help please.